# parfor for updating figure elements

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, matlab-figure, parfor

I am trying to speed up the update process for a figure window. I'm using it to generate a stimulation which has objects moving around the screen. I tried to separate all processes in an effort to speed up the window. Object coordinates are modified and all calculations are performed on matrices so the code wouldn't have to pull from each object, just update the position code.

The code works very well when left in a basic for loop. However when I try to incorporate a parfor loop to utilize parallel processing; the system stops working. Objects still appear on screen and in the appropriate spaces, nothing moves though.

Anyone know why this happens? I attached part of the code which is in question. I am building an object to hold all variables which is why I have the variable gh present.

```
function RunStim(gh)
figure(gh.StimWindow);                                          % select Stimulus window to display moving objects

TrialLength = 20;                                               % Length of trial to be run
Framerate = 60;                                                 % Freshrate of window
ObjSpeed = 20;                                                  % speed objects will travel across field

ObjList = gh.ObjectList;                                        % Container holding movable objects present in the figure
ObjLocX = gh.ObjectLocX;                                        % cell matrix containing object X locations (objects have varying sizes of points)
ObjLocY = gh.ObjectLocY;                                        % cell matrix containing object Y locations (objects have varying sizes of points)
ObjRotation = gh.ObjectRotation;                                % array containing list of objects rotations

NumofObj = length(ObjList);                                     % Number of Objects in stim system

timer = tic();                                                  % Timer for the stimulus            
moveforward = .03*.1*ObjSpeed;                                  % Reduce stepping by X amount to account for angular movement along a circle


while toc(timer) < TrialLength                                  % Run stimulus through length of project
    NextStepX = cellfun(@(x) x+moveforward,ObjLocX,'un',0);
    NextStepY = cellfun(@(x) x+moveforward,ObjLocY,'un',0);
    NextRot = ObjRotation + moveforward;

    parfor aa = 1:NumofObj
        ObjList{aa}.XData = NextStepX{aa};
    end

    ObjLocX = NextStepX;                                        % Update X location matrix for next step
    ObjLocY = NextStepY;                                        % Update Y location matrix for next step
    ObjRotation = NextRot;                                      % Update Rotation matrix for next step

    pause(1/Framerate)                                          % Pause window briefly to allow for drawing
end
```

Comment: My guess would be that MATLAB has difficulties with multiple workers all trying to write to the same display. I haven't done display stuff in parallel, but when writing to text files this is a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating `ObjList` in the `parfor` section, where

```
ObjList = gh.ObjectList;
```

is (I guess) a list of object handles.

The `parfor` copies sections of this array to all worker processes, which modify them and then send them back. The main process will then reassemble these sections into an array. It is likely that by now this new array is no longer referencing the original object handles in `gh.ObjectList`.

Note that these worker processes do not have access to the memory of the main process, and so will not be able to update the display.

In short, it should be the computations that are parallelized, not updating the figure.

---

`parfor` is not for multi-threaded computation, it starts new instances of MATLAB (by default locally, but in principle meant to be each running on a different computer in a cluster). Within a `parfor` loop you don't share memory, but you also don't share anything else. If a worker were to update a figure window, you wouldn't see it. See [Decide When to Use `parfor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/decide-when-to-use-parfor.html).

Note that most of MATLAB computations are multi-threaded by default, you don't need to do anything special for that.

Comment: You are right, the ObjList is a list of object handles. Is there a way pass the handles to and from a parfor loop? 

I remember long ago that GPU arrays could be used in matlab to update a series of subplots. I guess though is that the subplots are are in separate memory.

Comment: Sounds like my train of thought is flawed then. I'm trying to speed up drawing to a figure as I could potentially have 200 objects on screen at once. This can drastically slow down drawing and movement of the objects. I thought that if I could parallel updating the positions, it would potentially speed up drawing to the figure. This appears to not be the case.

Is there a function I'm missing that would solve this problem?

Comment: Would a gpuarray be appropriate for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: `gpuarray` is for computations, AFAIK. I don’t know if this is the best solution, but I would save each frame in a video, then play it back at whatever speed you want. You don’t share what these shapes are that you’re animating, but you should be able to animate thousands of points in real time. Maybe you find it slow because they are separate objects, rather than a single one with many points? Why not ask a new question about how to speed up your animation? Add a MCVE!

Comment: Thanks, I will write a new question about optimizing an animation. what does MCVE stand for?

Comment: @Hojo: MCVE stands for [mcve] — basically post a short bit of code that people can copy-paste and run as-is to reproduce your animation, then they’ve got something to work with. Minimal in that you should remove all redundant bits and leave something small and simple that shows the difficulty.